# The "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flaskblog'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

My package structure is as following:

```
--flaskblog
|   |--__init__.py
|   |--model.py
|   |--forms.py
|   |--routes.py
|____run.py
```

I am able to run the statement from `flaskblog import app`  in my `run.py` file but when I am trying to import `app` from `flaskblog` in `routes.py` file, I am getting the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flaskblog'"  error.

file contents of `run.py` file:

```
    from flaskblog import app

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

file contents of `__init__.py` file:

```
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask import Flask

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '5791628bb0b13ce0c676dfde280ba245'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

file contents of `routes.py` file are:

```
    from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect 
    from flaskblog import app 
    from flaskblog.forms import RegistrationForm, Loginform 
    from flaskblog.models import User, Post
```

I have checked the path multiple times yet I am not able to figure out where am I lacking. I have read similar questions on SO but nothing helped.

Comment: Are you trying to run the run.py file from any other location or directory may be in a server if so it is possible the error is because the location from where you are running the run.py python can't find flaskblog there.